# Java springframework remoting httpinvoker replacement

Tags: java, spring, remoting, httpinvoker

The spring framework in 5.3 and higher deprecated `org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker`

when we upgrade Spring to 5.3

wondering what is the replacement

our existing code base have:

```java
import org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor;

import org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean;

HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean proxy = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();

HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor re = new HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
```

what I could use to replace the class

Comment: There isn't (as apparent from the deprecation notice in the Javadoc). This is basically RPC over HTTP and RPC isn't really the best thing to use anymore. Use a REST or SOAP based approach instead.

Comment: deprecation remoting technologies [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25379)

Comment: According to the doc, the spring will remove those at 5.3, I try to use 5.2.15.release, but still tell me those class not found

Answer (score 0):

```
All the classes under org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker are deprecated when I am trying to migrate recently .But you can write some custom classes as similar to the below implementation .

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    
    public class CustomHttpInvokerClient {
        private String serviceUrl;
    
        public CustomHttpInvokerClient(String serviceUrl) {
            this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
        }
    
        public int add(int a, int b) throws IOException {
            return (int) invokeRemoteMethod("add", a, b);
        }
    
        public int subtract(int a, int b) throws IOException {
            return (int) invokeRemoteMethod("subtract", a, b);
        }
    
        public int multiply(int a, int b) throws IOException {
            return (int) invokeRemoteMethod("multiply", a, b);
        }
    
        public int divide(int a, int b) throws IOException {
            return (int) invokeRemoteMethod("divide", a, b);
        }
    
        private Object invokeRemoteMethod(String methodName, Object... arguments) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
           
          System.out.println("No error till now");
          
          BufferedReader br = null;
          if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
              br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
              String strCurrentLine;
                  while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                         System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                  }
          } else {
              br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
              String strCurrentLine;
                  while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                         System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                  }
          }
          
          
    
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                oos.writeObject(methodName);
                oos.writeObject(arguments);
            }
    
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream())) {
                return ois.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error deserializing response.", e);
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class MainApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Replace with the actual URL of your server-side application
            String serviceUrl = "http://localhost:9011/{your service name}/CalculatorService";
    
            CustomHttpInvokerClient customHttpInvokerClient = new CustomHttpInvokerClient(serviceUrl);
    
            try {
                int resultAdd = customHttpInvokerClient.add(10, 5);
                int resultSubtract = customHttpInvokerClient.subtract(10, 5);
                int resultMultiply = customHttpInvokerClient.multiply(10, 5);
                int resultDivide = customHttpInvokerClient.divide(10, 5);
    
                System.out.println("Add: " + resultAdd);
                System.out.println("Subtract: " + resultSubtract);
                System.out.println("Multiply: " + resultMultiply);
                System.out.println("Divide: " + resultDivide);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements CalculatorService {

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) throws IOException {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public int subtract(int a, int b) throws IOException {
        return a - b;
    }

    @Override
    public int multiply(int a, int b) throws IOException {
        return a * b;
    }

    @Override
    public int divide(int a, int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Division by zero");
        }
        return a / b;
    }
}

import java.io.IOException;

public interface CalculatorService {
    int add(int a, int b) throws IOException;
    int subtract(int a, int b) throws IOException;
    int multiply(int a, int b) throws IOException;
    int divide(int a, int b) throws IOException;
}
```